# Is there a workaround for APNS Feedback?

Tags: port, apple-push-notifications, web-hosting, feedback

The iOS app i developed uses APNS. Locally i could simulate the whole process from saving device tokens, sending push notifications to deleting device tokens with help from APNS feedback successfully. Also in production it worked for a short time.

Now my webhoster closed port 2196. Port 2195 is available, so sending notifications is still possible. I do not want my ios app to get on the blacklist, so is there any other way to register whether a user has deleted my app on their device? Or will i have to look around for another webhoster, who has both ports open? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to look for another host or look into 3rd party solutions that have a Feedback API. I know Urban Airship had one (haven't used it in a while) and may be giving access to it freely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have now been looking at 3rd party solutions, like the one you mentioned, also (pushwoosh and push wizard). They offer a lot, but still i think the best solution in my case, because i have everything already set up to my needs, is to look for another host, which have both ports open.